# Hard Drive Space Weirdness

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

I've been trying to free up space on my hard drive for a large game. I went through and cleaned out at least 15-20GB (probably even more) of data between downloaded games, their saves, and the game data itself. But for some reason, the PS3 reports that I've only opened up a Gigabyte of space.

I tried restarting, but it didn't change anything. I'm not sure if it's just a small system glitch or what, but I do know that I deleted well more than 10 Gigabytes of data. Two of the games were just over 6000 Megabytes, as well as one that was 11 Gigabytes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Looking into this, there has to be something missing here.

Is this the internal drive or some external USB by chance?

Answer (score 1):

[Go into Recovery Menu](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-Support/How-to-access-the-PlayStation-3-Recovery-Menu/td-p/19195118) and choose Restore File System and Rebuild Database. It might just be a small glitch that still recognizes the space of the games even though they were already deleted.